# Django Directory Structure / Module Not Found

Tags: django, directory-structure, webfaction

I use WebFaction for hosting. 
On their website I created a Django project. 
It gave me this directory setup:

> /home/account_username/webapps/app_name/myproject/myproject/

- Why "myproject" is used twice here?
- I do not understand what each directory should be used for.
- I do not understand which files should be in each directory.

  Here is what's inside each directory:

> app_name
>   
>           
>   apache2 
>           
>   bin 
>           
>   myproject 
>                   
>   manage.py 
>                   
>   myproject 
>                           
>   **init**.py 
>                           
>   **init**.pyc 
>                           
>   settings.py 
>                           
>   settings.pyc 
>                           
>   tests.py 
>                           
>   urls.py 
>                           
>   urls.pyc 
>                           
>   views.py 
>                           
>   views.pyc 
>                           
>   wsgi.py
>
> What is the first "myproject" directory supposed to be used for?
>
> What do most people name this directory?
>
> What is the second "myproject" directory supposed to be used for?
>
> What do most people name this directory?

Answer (score 1):

WebFaction is using Django 1.4 and default project layout is been changed. See the [Django 1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py) for more details. You will get all answers.